# Select Statement getting overridden in job variables file

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I'm running a tdload command using a job variables file with values :

```
SelectStmt = 'select * from database.tablename where column1 > 100',
SourceTdpid = 'hostid',
SourceUserName =  'username',
SourceUserPassword = 'password'
SourceTable  = 'database.tablename',
FileWriterFileSizeMax = '10M',
TargetTextDelimiter = '|'
TargetFilename = "file.csv"
FileWriterQuotedData =  "Y"
```

The filter clause in the select statement should return me only 39 rows,

but I'm getting all of the rows from the table in the extracted file.

How to resolve this?

Comment: What happens if you run that exact statement in SQL Assistant?

Comment: SourceTable is overriding the prior SelectStmt with a `SELECT * FROM databasename.tablename;` - don't use both

Answer (score 0):

Had to use `ExportSelectStmt` instead of `SelectStmt`

Comment: And the specific operator-prefixed variable overrides both generic ones (SourceTable and SelectStmt).